# Android Kotlin - GDPR consent message not showing

Tags: android, kotlin

The code:

```
fun loadForm() {

    UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
        this,
        {
            if (consentInformation.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {

                Log.d("pikaboo", "show form")

                consentForm.show(
                    this,
                    ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener {
                        if (consentInformation.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                            Log.d("pikaboo", "done, set ads")
                        }else{
                            Log.d("pikaboo", "dismiss")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        },
        {
            Log.d("pikaboo", "error")
        }
    )
}
```

it only prints "show form" but doesn't continue.

I'm already using AdMob for years and get the payments and it's connected to AdSense.

Comment: It's really hard to tell you why, without seeing the `consentForm.show`

Comment: consentForm is from this library: com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0 got it from the almost always bad/incomplete google docs: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy @GilGoldzweig

Comment: Did you set the `DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA` for testing?

Comment: I did but it doesn't work so I removed it again. I have also set it to "show to all" anyway while creating it in play console